# GnuTLS: Error during import of Certifcate

Tags: c++, x509certificate, x509, pem, gnutls

I run into a problem importing a certificate using GnuTLS library. I generated a self-signed certificate which I want to import into my C++ code, to further process it. I read the certificate using `fopen`. I save this to a `gnutls_datum_t-type` , which seems to be a tuple of a `FILE-type` and the `length of the FILE-type`. Why does my code throw the `Error Value: -207` which means `Base64 unexpected header error`.

When I look up the type of teh Certificate it tells me to be `pkix-cert+pem`, but I also tried a `x-x509-cert`. All generated using certtool.

When I change the expecting format for the input the error value changes to -73 which means ASN1 parser: Error in TAG

When I print the FILE-type, I can see the usual Certificate structure.

what is my fault?

Comment: Maybe your certificate is just not in `PEM` format (which is base64 encoded data) and `GNUTLS_X509_FMT_DER` would do the job?

Comment: @frymode This changes the problem to **-73: ASN1 parser: Error in TAG**

Answer (score 0):

`gnutls_datum_t` is a buffer and its length.

This might initialize it given some text `certPem`:

```
gnutls_datum_t certDat;
certDat.data = (unsigned char *)certPem;
certDat.size = strlen(certPem) + 1;
```